# How to insert object via push method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I cannot add an object via push method to javascript, my code is:

```
arrObj = [
    {
        name: "Krunal",
        age: 26,
    },
    {
        name: "Ankit",
        age: 24,
    },
];

function onAdd() {
    return CART.push(arrObj);
}
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: What is `CART`?

Comment: Try the reverse: `arrObj.push(CART)`. Does it work?

Comment: Since you've omitted the definition of `CART` this question is unanswerable. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: If `CART` is an array it works fine, although you may not be *returning* what you think you are. But we cannot see `CART`, so... :shrug:

Comment: @George You are eligible to get the [`Peer pressure`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) badge ;)

Comment: It's also not clear what the *intent* is: do you *want* `CART` (assuming it's an array) to include an *additional* array (the array of objects) or do you want the array-being-pushed "flattened" inside `CART`?

Answer (score 0):

*if* `CART` is an array, you should use `.concat()` instead

```
const newArray = CART.concat(arrObj)
```

as `arr1.concat(arr2)` will concat two arrays and return the result

whereas `arr1.push(arr2)` will result in an array *within* an array

Comment: It might be helpful to explain *why* `concat` should be used instead, since `push` is a perfectly fine way to add an element to an array. (Also noting that we don't know the OP's *intent*, e.g., they may *want* an array inside `CART` instead of a concat.)